CSP and inline styles from color picker
I am using CSP on my website to keeps things locked down as much as possible. I have an HTML editor on the website, and I wanted to allow users to choose text colors from a color picker. This involves adding style="color:#XXXXXX" to the affected elements, where XXXXXX is a 24-bit value from the color picker. I am temporarily using style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' on my test rig to allow inline styles to be used to define the colors. But this would open me up to CSS injection attacks if I did it on the live system.
Is there any way to reliably sanitise CSS to allow inline styles to be used safely in this situation, or is there another way to safeguard inline styles so that only the editor can define them (maybe using nonces, which I use to add JS event handlers to HTML elements)?

If you're already using JavaScript, don't set the color with the style HTML attribute. Instead, set the color directly with JavaScript:
document.getElementById('some-element').style.color = "#123456";


Aha, good idea. I can then store it in my DB with a custom data-color attribute, and then use JS to set the style the same way from any data-color attributes when I display it.

I've marked this as answering the question, but I'd still like to hear if anyone has any ideas about sanitizing CSS in general....

I feel like this could be another case of the XY problem. Why exactly do you need to sanitize CSS?

To avoid CSS injection attacks. See https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/v41/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/11-Client_Side_Testing/05-Testing_for_CSS_Injection

Why would you need to prevent a CSS injection attack? Unless you're storing raw user input on the server and sending that raw input back to the client (which you hopefully aren't doing anyways)...

What's the problem with my trying to avoid CSS injection attacks? But, for your benefit, let me explain. I have a contenteditable HTML editor where users can also view and edit the raw HTML where necessary. At the moment I sanitize by removing tags like 
Another approach I've been referred to by a friend is to use the OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer, if like me your webapp uses Java servlets. It is open source, so could in principal be ported to other languages.
